# React Native Error - Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, crash

I'm encountering an error while working on a React Native project and I'm hoping someone can help me troubleshoot.
The error message I'm seeing is:
[image: Error Image - Malformed calls from JS: field sizes are different]